# Clicking on text in between SPAN tags using Selenium Webdriver (java)

Tags: java, selenium, html

HTML code looks like this:

```
<td id="id26a" class="doclisting-name link" style="width: 319px; min-width: 319px;"> 

<span id="id26b" title="Document">
<span class="ie-fallback-marker">
  words

</span></span></td>
```

I cannot search for Element ID, as it changes all the time. I cannot search for the element's class, as there are multiples which could change locations.

I want to be able to click on "WORDS" *in between* the SPAN tags. Is this at all possible?

This is what I used so far, but neither seems to work:

```
//string document is words.
   public void testscenario123(String document)      throws Throwable {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.linkText(document)).click();
}
```

or

```
  //string document is words.
 public void testscenario124(String document) throws Throwable {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[contains(@span,'"+document+"')]")).click();
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with. Same as before. I think it might be the program not responding to the correct code though, not the solution given...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select xpath via text and normalize-space will strip white space:

```
  //string document is words.
 public void testscenario124(String document) throws Throwable {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[normalize-space()='"+document+"']")).click();
}
```

You may also wish to consider waiting for the element to appear instead of declaring an explicit sleep

Comment: Doesn't help either unfortunately... 

Concerning the sleep, I considered that aswell, but the waitforelementpresent results in a ridiculous piece of code. We also have a DoD which states that a page needs to be loaded within 3 seconds...

Comment: Ahh, just realised, you need to change the xpath to; //span[contains(@class, 'ie-fallback-marker') and normalize-space()='words'].   Also I am interested as to why waiting makes a 'ridiculous piece of code'?

Comment: Strangly enough, That did the trick! Thanks a million! Just curious on one thing: 'words' doesn't have any whites, so why does the element need to 'remove whites'?

Comment: It is surrounded by white space

Comment: actually, that's a typo... There are no spaces around the real code, but somehow your solution does the trick :)

Comment: ok, in that case try it with 'text()="words"'.  It is the @class which worked for you

Answer (score 3):

I suspect the element is taking more than 3 seconds to appear.Hence the following exception is thrown.

> Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with

To avoid this exception [implicit or explicit wait](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits) must be used.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(., \"" + document + "\")]"))).click();
```

As RobbieWareham has mentioned,even i'm interested to know more about this `waiting makes a ridiculous piece of code?`

Through Selenium Webdriver,we are just trying to imitate how a user would work.Even he/she has to wait for the element to appear to perform some operation.

Comment: I have to automate Hippo CMS. It has a basic map structure on the left side. Clicking on a certain directory opens a list of documents on the main frame. in THAT frame, I want selenium to click a certain type of document. When I inspect the element when the script stops, it doesn't show the clickable link, but it does show it on the screen. I believe Hippo CMS is being generated by javascript and widgets, which are just.so.awefull to work with.

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
driver.findElement(By.xPath("//span[starts-with(., \"" + document + "\")]")).click();
```

It worked for me!
In case you want to check some text in the middle, try:

```
driver.findElement(By.xPath("//span[contains(., \"" + document + "\")]")).click();
```

Comment: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with. Unfortunately, it doesn't work :/

Answer (score 1):

I see no reasons why following xpath wouldn't work

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(), \"" + document + "\")]"));
```

Also, you probably need your input string to be constant

```
//string document is words.
   public void testscenario123(final String document)      throws Throwable {
```

---

If you were to get `ElementNotVisibleException` then check if your locator is returning you the correct element, perhaps there is another `<span>` element present containing the text in the `document` variable.

Comment: Well, it does work on all other pages, so this is a fix :) thanks for that. Now I just need to click something that is hidden, which Ill try and research right now.

Answer (score -2):

We can use xPath to find such an element, because the text is inside the span tag. Below is the code snippet...

```
WebElement elmnt=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='MainLayout']/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/div/div[4]/span/span"));

elmnt.click();
```